# A while loop that stops after a certian number is entered

Tags: java

I am trying to write a program that takes in grades numbers from the user, and stops when -1 is entered. But, every time I enter -1 the while loop continues to run, how do I stop it from running?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class getLetterGrade {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        int count = 0;
        while (count >= 0)
            getGrade();
        count++;
        System.out.println("You entered" + " " + count + " " + "Student(s)");
    }

    public static void getGrade() {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        double grade;

        System.out.println("Welcome to the grade calculator. \n Please enter a numeric grade. \n After the last student in the class, enter a grade of -1.");
        grade = reader.nextDouble();

        if (grade >= 90)
            System.out.println("That's an A");
        else if (grade >= 80 && grade < 90)
            System.out.println("That's an B");
        else if (grade >= 70 && grade < 80)
            System.out.println("That's an C");
        else if (grade >= 60 && grade < 70)
            System.out.println("That's an D");
        else if (grade <= 50 && grade > 0)
            System.out.println("That's an F");
        if (grade == -1)
            System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

Comment: why did you instantiate 2 Scanner when you're not using the first one you created? and please use proper curly braces for readability of code.

Comment: remove the `Scanner` from main. make `getGrade()` return bolean and change `while (count >= 0)` to `while(getGrade())`

Comment: You probably meant to include the `count++` in the while loop, but at no stage do you ever set count to a negative number, so the while loop will never end.

Comment: Worth noting that while needs curly braces if the scope is longer than one line.

Comment: Just a note - it's a good habit to get into closing your `Scanner` objects.  But failing to close a `Scanner` that's sourced from `System.in` won't cause a resource leak or a memory leak, because `System.in` itself won't ever get closed.

Answer (score 1):

You could move the loop down into the other method, make it an "endless" loop, and use `return` to exit from it.  You can then return the count from that method and show it in `main`.

It might then look like this.  Note that I've simplified your branching logic too, and removed the double entendre from the output message.

I have also used a try-with-resources block, which is one way of making sure you *always* close the scanner, and avoid resource leaks.  Not strictly needed in this case, but still a good habit to get into.

**Edit** As the Scary Wombat has pointed out, you could add an `else` clause to deal with the case where the user inputs an invalid grade if you really wanted to.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GetLetterGrade {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int count = getGrades();
        System.out.println("You entered " + count + " grade(s)");
    }

    public static int getGrades() {
        try(Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            int count = 0;

            while(true) {
                System.out.println("Welcome to the grade calculator. \n Please enter a numeric grade. \n After the last student in the class, enter a grade of -1.");


                double grade = reader.nextDouble();

                if (grade >= 90) {
                    System.out.println("That's an A");
                } else if (grade >= 80 ) {
                    System.out.println("That's a B");
                } else if (grade >= 70) {
                    System.out.println("That's a C");
                } else if (grade >= 60) {
                    System.out.println("That's a D");
                } else if (grade >= 0) {
                    System.out.println("That's an F");
                } else if (grade == -1) {
                    return count;
                }
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: More coffee needed

Comment: @ScaryWombat There is, of course, a slightly more elegant solution using a `TreeMap<Double, String>` and the `floorEntry` method, but it's probably not suitable for beginners.

Comment: Also if you do not close your `Scanner` you will get earthquakes.

Comment: Ah, so they were my fault!  Please don't dob me in to the New Zealand government.   Actually, by rights, I should use a try-with-resources in case `nextDouble` throws an exception.  I'll edit this.

Answer (score 1):

A few things that need to be changed... First, your loop keeps looping because you never set `count` to less then 0, so the condition is always true. You also create 2 `Scanner` objects, but only ever use the second one (in `getGrade()`).

Try this code, and have a look at the comments to see everything that's changed:

```
    public class getLetterGrade  {

    static Scanner reader;      //Add reader as member variable

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);  //Remove this unused Scanner
        int count = 0;
        reader = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (getGrade())      //Change the condition here so the loop will continue while getGrade() returns true.
            count++;

        reader.close();     //Close the Scanner
        System.out.println("You entered" + " " + count + " " + "Student(s)");
    }

    public static boolean getGrade() {      //getGrade() returns a boolean...


        System.out.println("Welcome to the grade calculator. \n Please enter a numeric grade. \n After the last student in the class, enter a grade of -1.");
        double grade = reader.nextDouble();  //Consider using a try/catch block here.


        if (grade >= 90)
            System.out.println("That's an A");
        else if (grade >= 80 && grade < 90)
            System.out.println("That's an B");
        else if (grade >= 70 && grade < 80)
            System.out.println("That's an C");
        else if (grade >= 60 && grade < 70)
            System.out.println("That's an D");
        else if (grade <= 50 && grade > 0)
            System.out.println("That's an F");
        else if(grade != -1)
            System.out.println("Invaled input!"); //Print if 'grade' is something other then the above statements.
        if (grade == -1) {                      //Add brackets
            System.out.println("");
            return false;                       //return false if -1 was entered...
        }
        return true;                            //else return true
    }
}
```

Comment: Please let me know what I can improve?

Comment: @ScaryWombat Wow. Can't believe I missed that... I did run it, but I guess I added that after. >< Will edit now...

Comment: @ScaryWombat Should be fixed now, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: As `reader` is now a field, you can do `reader = new Scanner(System.in);` in main rather multiple times in `getGrade`

Comment: Just changed that before I saw your comment. ;) Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

      public class GetLetterGrade {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
        int count = 0;
        while (getGrade() >= 0.0){
            count++;
            System.out.println("You entered" + " " + count + " " + "Student(s)");   
        }

    }

    public static double  getGrade() {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        double grade;

        System.out.println("Welcome to the grade calculator. \n Please enter a numeric grade. \n After the last student in the class, enter a grade of -1.");
       grade = reader.nextDouble();

        if (grade >= 90)
            System.out.println("That's an A");
        else if (grade >= 80 && grade < 90)
            System.out.println("That's an B");
        else if (grade >= 70 && grade < 80)
            System.out.println("That's an C");
        else if (grade >= 60 && grade < 70)
            System.out.println("That's an D");
        else if (grade <= 50 && grade > 0)
            System.out.println("That's an F");
        if (grade == -1)
            System.out.println("");
        return grade ;
    }
}
```

Comment: `System.out.println("You entered" + " " + count + " " + "Student(s)");` should be outside the `while`

Comment: please add some description in your answer.

Answer (score -1):

Your while loop always takes the 0 value and get in to while loop thats why it didn't stop..

import java.util.Scanner;

public class getLetterGrade {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Welcome to the grade calculator. \n  After the last student in the class, enter a grade of -1.");
    int count = 0;
    int no = -1;
    while (count != -1) {
        no++;
        System.out.println("Please enter the value:-");
        count = reader.nextInt();

        if (count >= 90) {
            System.out.println("That's an A");
        } else if (count >= 80 && count < 90) {
            System.out.println("That's an B");
        } else if (count >= 70 && count < 80) {
            System.out.println("That's an C");
        } else if (count >= 60 && count < 70) {
            System.out.println("That's an D");
        } else if (count <= 59 && count > 0) {
            System.out.println("That's an F");
        }
        if (count == -1) {
            break;
        }
    }
    count++;
    System.out.println("You entered" + " " + no + " " + "Student(s)");
}
```

}

Comment: How does it print this line `System.out.println("You entered" + " " + count + " " + "Student(s)");` ?

Comment: System.out.println("You entered -1...Thank you for using Grade System..");
}